# How to check JDK version in Oracle?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g

We have a Java class within our Oracle DB and recently one line of code in that java class is throwing an error:

```
static BASE64Encoder B64 = new BASE64Encoder();
```

We are seeing error

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

on this line of code.

I am not sure what has changed on the DB side as we don't have SYS privileges or access to host.

I wish to check the JDK version running our Oracle DB --

> Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production.

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/faq-jvm-java-stored-procedures-097205.html#_How_to_check you can check this link.

Comment: select * from all_registry_banners  doesn't gives me the JDK version

Answer (score 35):

```sql
SELECT  dbms_java.get_ojvm_property(PROPSTRING=>'java.version') FROM dual
```

Answer (score 13):

**solution 1)** on the database host

```
cd $ORACLE_HOME/jdk/bin
java -version
```

**solution 2)** create a PL/SQL function to return Java system properties

```
create function get_java_property(prop in varchar2)
return varchar2 is
language java name 'java.lang.System.getProperty(java.lang.String) return java.lang.String';
```

And the run a select for the Java version

```
select get_java_property('java.version') from dual;
```

**solution 3)** check the answer from [SteveK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3511166/stevek)

Comment: I don't have access to host, also is there no in-built sql command which will do this?

Comment: If you have the grant to create a PL/SQL function use the second solution I posted. Otherwise if you have no access to the database host nor have the grant to create a PL/SQL function you could rely on the list of certified versions or ask someone who administrate the server.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have access to create a function.

Comment: The java in $ORACLE_HOME/jdk/bin does not necessarily have the same version as the embedded JVM.

Comment: @KarstenSpang Could you please provide an example in which official Oracle database setup it would be not the case. (It might be that within the last five years there is now such a case.)

Answer (score 13):

Certified versions are:

> Oracle 12.2 / 18.1 JVM is [1.8](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/jjdev/support-java-8.html#GUID-6B31C8D9-0489-4E1F-9CDF-B9AF9E685D71)
>
> The Oracle **12c** database embedded [JVM supports **JDK 1.6 and 1.7**](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDEV/chone.htm#JJDEV13628)
>
> The Oracle **11g >= 11.2.0.4** database embedded [JVM supports **JDK 1.6**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e10588/chone.htm#JJDEV13039)
>
> The Oracle **11g** database embedded [JVM supports **JRE 1.5**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/whatsnew.htm#JJDEV00100).
>
> The Oracle **10g** database embedded JVM supports **JRE 1.4**.
>
> The Oracle **9i** database embedded JVM supports **JRE 1.3**

Comment: Where have you find this info? I am searching it on the internet but only found your post that is absolutelly right.. but from where you copied that?

Comment: @kupa i really don't remember the source, could be multiple with brief here.

Comment: I was trying to update jdk up to 8 by update_javavm_binaries.pl but saw that  Valid options are: 6 7, Then was trying to make somehow jdk 8 available inside /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dblb/javavm/jdk  but couldn't .. I was searching supporting matrix on metalink, on google but couldn't find that.. Your post made me clear where I was wrong.. So thank you!

Comment: For anyone that stumbles across this, source is 342810.1.