# Importing apache-poi into Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, apache-poi

Good morning,

I would like to generate excel file from oracle, therefore I have imported poi 3.16 and all pre-requisits based on the bottom table in  this link:
http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components
Exctly the following files:
commons-logging, commons-codec, commons-collections, log4j  ,poi.jar

The dbms command  I have used:
dbms_java.loadjava('filename.jar -resolve');

Everything went fine but all the classes that are within "org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/" remained invalid. The most important part. :)

Anybody has any idea what can be the problem? Should I import any other classes? First I would like try solution that does not need to check log files on the harddisk or any action on the server itself. I have no access to the server, therefore I have to communicate with the administrators which is complicated in our company :(. Of course if there is no olution within oracle I have no other option...

Thanks in advance,
Sz.

Comment: The JVM inside Oracle is not fully compatible with the Standard JVM (some limitations I've met myself were not even documented). You can fight with that for some time, but this may require modifications in apache-poi source code in order to fit inside the database JVM.

Comment: Which Oracle version do you have? (see [JDK compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28164252)) ... POI 3.16 needs JDK 1.6 ... I haven't got experiences on importing jars with dependencies into Oracle and therefore don't know if this really works, but security-wise this is an accident waiting to happen - I would never process arbitrary files directly in the Oracle database environment ...

Comment: Thank you very much for both answers. Lesson  learnt: Always check by yourself the versions instead of trusting in any internal policy,document,rules...etc. 1.6 is the java officially used in the company, except on the developer server I am using. They forgot to update it.... No comment. So, I have downloaded the version apache poi 3.5 and it works without problem. Thanks again.

Comment: I think it is better to write a program (using Java?) to handle your task.